# Access WebService variable in projects referenced by the webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, scope

I have a .net c# web service that references other projects to achieve whatever it needs to.

I need to have a variable set with a unique guid for each call to a web method in the webservice.

The variable/value does not need to be visible/accessible/outputted to the consumers of the webservice.

This variable(the value in the variable) should be accessible in the projects that the webservice references, but i cannot explicitly pass it as a parameter to any of the functions in the projects.

The variable/value only needs to be alive for the lifetime of the webmethod call and be reset for each new call to the web method.

What kind of variable(static, global, local etc.) should be used and where should it be declared?

Thanks!

Comment: *"I cannot explicitly pass it as a parameter to any of the functions in the projects."* - is it a "thought experiment" requirement  or a real technical constraint for you?

Comment: Currently it is a real technical constraint. In the worst case scenario, I guess the constraint will need to be dropped. but that will involve significant code change across quite a few projects and functions.

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make sense. What do you want to do if there are two calls to the same webmethod at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to whoever had answered(but strangely deleted the answer) and suggested using InternalsVisibleTo attribute.